# How to cite properly cite an unpublished paper with correct note shown instead of year?

Tags: citing, natbib

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I am using the natbib package for citations in my report. However I encounter a problem in citing an unpublished paper.

```
@unpublished{unpublishedkey,
author  = "Dummy, D1 D2",
title   = "Title",
note    = "unpublished"
}
```

When I use \citep{unpublishedkey}, I obtain

> (Dummy, ????)

In the bibliography it shows,

> Dummy, D.D. (????). Title. unpublished.

I try to add "unpublished" in the year field, but because of the truncation, it doesn't work properly:

```
@unpublished{unpublishedkey,
author  = "Dummy, D1 D2",
title   = "Title",
year    = "unpublished"
note    = "unpublished"
}
```

> (Dummy, shed)
>
> Dummy, D.D. (unpublished). Title

Isn't the year field optional in an unpublished bibtex entry, and how could I have the citation as the following instead?

> (Dummy, unpublished)
>
> Dummy, D.D. Title. unpublished.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An author-year citation system needs a year. `;-)` Even if a paper is unpublished, it has been written.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, is it possible to also display the note of the unpublished entry? I'm asking because in the bibliography, the entry becomes "Dummy, D.D. (2016). Title." even I had the note "unpublished".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign a year, based on when you received the unpublished paper or use one of the following methods:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{unpublishedkeyA,
author  = {Dummy, D1 D2},
title   = {Title},
year    = {N.D.},
note    = {unpublished},
}
@unpublished{unpublishedkeyB,
author  = {Dummy, D1 D2},
title   = {Title},
year    = {\ndd},
note    = {unpublished},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand{\ndd}{Unpublished}

\begin{document}

Example of citation: \citep{unpublishedkeyA}

Another: \citet{unpublishedkeyA}

Example of citation: \citep{unpublishedkeyB}

Another: \citet{unpublishedkeyB}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

You can define `\ndd` any way you like.

[image]

[image]